# Hibernate query setParameter not working

Tags: hibernate

I have the following query

```
select count(lead.leadId) as cnt from IRLead lead,IRUser usr,IRLeadWorkflowDtls ld,IRLeadWorkflowState ls where usr.userId = lead.userId and ld.leadId = lead.leadId and ls.id=ld.actionId and ld.currentlyActive=lead.active and lead.orgId= :orgId and lead.active = true and ( lead.firstName LIKE :searchText or lead.email LIKE :searchText or lead.lastName LIKE :searchText or lead.mobile LIKE :searchText or lead.phone LIKE :searchText )  order by lead.firstName asc"
```

Then i use the following code to setParameters,

```
    Query q = session.createQuery(query.toString());
    q = q.setParameter("orgId", orgId);

     //this loop to check named parameters
    for(String paraName:q.getNamedParameters())
    {
        System.err.println("ParaName "+ paraName);
    }

    for(String name:params.keySet())
    {
        System.err.println(name+" --- "+params.get(name));

        q = q.setParameter(name, params.get(name));
    }

    if (pageNo >= 0)
    {
        q.setFirstResult(pageNo * 10);
        q.setMaxResults(10);
    }
    List<Object[]> objs = q.list();
```

But I am getting the following exception,

```
     org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [:searchText]
     at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:107)
```

What am I missing here? It's driving me nuts.

Ayush

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are setting a parameter in the query with the name plus the prefix `:`.

Modify this

```
    q = q.setParameter(name, params.get(name));
```

to this:

```
    q = q.setParameter(name.replace(":",""), params.get(name));
```

This is a quickly/dirt solution. What you should really do is to remove the prefix `:` when you are creating the `params` map.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of problem of such type is - **final** Query query ... in var declaration.
To make it able to setParameter, remove - final !